# How to get vertex snapping to snap to one vertex

Tags: modeling, transforms, snapping

The following image is my failed attempt to make a sword handle's surface meet the blade's bottom. How can I snap the blade's bottom to the handle?

[image: vertex snapping]

Comment: by meet , do you mean move the sword blade to the handle surface so it looks like they are connected , or did you you want to merge vertices so it is one piece?

Comment: so that they are not overlapping, but are touching.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are wanting to do is make those two segments, the handle and base, into one solid object.

Well, the easiest way I would recommend doing this is to select the two objects in Object mode, then apply a boolean modifier set to union. This will instantly merge the two objects together for you.

Here's a tutorial that helped me understand using boolean modifiers better if you aren't familiar with them: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pcUe-ab_jQs

Answer (score 0):

Set the snap target to closest and snap element to face:
[image]

[image]