# Snap vertices without overlapping

Tags: snapping

Im trying to get them to not overlap, but be snapped together. the center of the one i move snaps to the vertex of the idle one.

[image]

Comment: It's not very clear what you want from your screenshot. Do you want to merge vertices which are snapped to the same location? Try enabling *Auto merge*

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [*Snap Element*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Snap) to *Face*:

[image]

Comment: can you post a gif?

Comment: @AidanPallian Same as here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20893/i-want-2-vertexs-to-snap-but-the-center-snaps-to-the-vertex-instead you shouldn't post a qustion twice.